# Is it possible to push to 2 or more remote repositories at the same time?

Tags: git, git-push

Is it possible to push to 2 or more remote repositories at the same
time?

I only want to mirror the main repository, where most if not all the
pulls will come from.

Answer (score 0):

If not, if you find youself doing the same push and want to speed things up, you could make an alias in your shell for as many commands as you need.

And you don't need to pull from the same places just because you push to them